# Emacs - Clojure function highlighting (i.e. map, reduce, println, get, etc.)

Tags: emacs, clojure

I am currently using emacs24 with clojure-mode as my clojure IDE. I use the zenburn theme.

As far as I can tell, clojure-mode only provides syntax-highlighting for macros. Is there a way to add syntax highlighting for all clojure native functions?

I've googled a bit and it seems like I'm either the only one who wants this, or the only one that doesn't have it for some strange reason. I don't think my .emacs file is a necessary addition to this question but I'll add it if someone wants to take a look.

Thank you.

Comment: Also, which version of `clojure-mode` are you using? Version 3.0 [just came out](http://batsov.com/articles/2014/09/05/clojure-mode-3-dot-0/), and apparently has "much improved font-locking support across the board".

Comment: One of the aspects of the improved font-locking is reducing the false positives that (the attempt of) font-locking all built-in functions was producing (quite a lot, as those names can exist in other namespaces as well). Therefore this font-locking was removed and moved to a separate package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly enable font locking for these functions with `clojure-mode-extra-font-locking`.  Install this package from MELPA, and add the following to your `init.el`:

```lisp
(eval-after-load 'clojure-mode '(require 'clojure-mode-extra-font-locking))
```

Comment: Btw, there's a reason this is not done by default - it simply can't be done properly as functions with the same names as the "core" functions can exist pretty much everywhere. I think everyone would be better off not using this, but the option exists.

Comment: @BozhidarBatsov One could argue that this is a good thing, because it alerts you when you are shadowing a clojure.core function!